Don't receive push notification for data-only message in react native fcm
My task is I will need to customize remote notification phone with contact name. I am in half way when I try to send data-only message with this format:
{
  "data": {
    ...
    "body": "[phone] approved your proposed S$20.00 contribution",
    "title": "App Name"
    "content-available": true
  },
  "from": "275845609097",
  "messageId": "1712017406867021",
  "apns": {
             "payload": {
                 "aps": {
                     "content-available": true
                 }
             },
             "headers": {
                 "apns-push-type": "background"
                 "apns-priority": "5"
                 "apns-topic": "com.*.*"
             }
         },
// "notification": {
//    "body": "[phone] approved your proposed S$20.00 contribution",
//    "title": "App Name"
//  }
  "android": {
      "priority": "high"
    }
}


But after I remove notification prop nothing send to my phone any more, also with setBackgroundMessageHandler and onMessage, I tried console.log but nothing show up. I already try simulator and real device but still the same. My react-native and fcm version is:
"react-native": "^0.72.7", 
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.8.0",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^18.8.0"


i found solution . I add 2 more properties of notification payload:
"mutable_content": true,
"content_available" : true


Where did you added those? Would you like to share the full payload?
